# How to include a module from another Cookbook's library?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have the following setup:

```
cookbooks/
         cookbook1/libraries/prom.rb
         cookbook2/templates/default/execute.erb
```

in `prom.rb`:

```
module Prom
   class exporter # with several methods
```

How can I reuse this module when generating `execute.rb`? I've tried adding `depends 'cookbook1'` and require, but no luck..

Comment: It's a module, so you need to include it and not require it. `include Prom` in your recipe should do the work.

Comment: yes I can include it that way in the recipe, but I need to use the module in the output from erb template if that makes sense.

I tried including it in the helpers for template, but no luck still

Comment: Don't, make it a variable to the template resource and use this variable in your template :) Can't do better advice without the exemple code to work on